Attempting to get the viewValue(the text) rather than the value from the multiple select in Angular
I can get the values associated with the multiple select, but want the text instead to display the programs selected. Angular 14.2
Typescript class
export class AffinityProgramsComponent {
  title = 'Affinity Program Extension Form';
  affinityForm = new FormGroup({
    cid!: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    affinityprogramid!: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  })

  selectFormControl = new FormControl<Program | null>(null, Validators.required);

  selectedProgram = '';

  programsList: Program[] = [
    { value: '2', viewValue: 'Merchant card connect' },
    { value: '9', viewValue: 'xx credit card credit reporting' },
    { value: '28', viewValue: 'Legal services' },
    { value: '27', viewValue: 'Hx' },
    { value: '3', viewValue: 'xx' },
    { value: '25', viewValue: 'xxxx Executive Groups' },
    { value: '24', viewValue: 'xx Coverage' },
    { value: '26', viewValue: 'xxforce' },
    { value: '22', viewValue: 'HxxB' }
  ];
}

HTML
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-additional-selection">
  <mat-label class="example-additional-selection-no-border">Affinity Program</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple class="example-additional-selection-no-border" matNativeControl required [formControl]="selectFormControl" [(value)]="selectedProgram">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let program of programsList" [value]="program.value" class="example-additional-selection2">
      {{program.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="selectFormControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an program</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<div><small class="example-additional-selection-no-border">These are the programs selected: {{selectedProgram}}</small></div>


Incase of Multiple select when you try to read the selected value , it will return values as one Dimensional Array.
In Above Case it will return as :
[2,29,8].=> Array of selected value.
but you want the Viewvalue then you can have below two Options.
1.Pass ViewValue as [value]
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-additional-selection">
  <mat-label class="example-additional-selection-no-border">Affinity Program</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple class="example-additional-selection-no-border" matNativeControl required [formControl]="selectFormControl" [(value)]="selectedProgram">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let program of programsList" [value]="program.viewValue" class="example-additional-selection2">
      {{program.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="selectFormControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an program</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<div><small class="example-additional-selection-no-border">These are the programs selected: {{selectedProgram}}</small></div>

2.You can Filter out the ViewValue from Array Using selected Value Array
For Eg.using your above scenarios, you will receive Values as.
In Above Case it will return as :
[2,29,8].=> Array of selected value.
let SelectedValue = [2,29,8];
let SelectedtextValue = [];

SelectedValue.forEach(x => {
    let TextValue = this.programsList.filter(y => y.value == x)[0];
    SelectedtextValue.push(TextValue );
});
console.log("SelectedtextValue" ,SelectedtextValue);


This is causing an error on the y.value in the foreach...
Error TS2367 (TS) This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.

How is the second example getting the values from the mat-select?

In Mat-select Multi select , you receive values as a Array.so In second Example I am just iterating through that array only.
